# How to deselect an already selected in list view.builder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

Am trying to implement single selection on my `listview.builder` such that on tap of an item, the others get deselected and only the last taps gets selected. This is my logic but it does multiple selection for now and am stuck on how to make it single.

```
                         FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _bloc.similarProducts[index].selected =
                                !_bloc.similarProducts[index].selected;
                              });
                            },
                            child:  Container(
                              height: 45,
                              width:120,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color:!_bloc.similarProducts
                                  [index].selected?
                                  Colors.white:
                                  Hexcolor("#DADE66"),
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                                color:  !_bloc.similarProducts[index].selected?
                                Hexcolor("#DADE66"):
                                Colors.white,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0, right:15.0),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    !_bloc.similarProducts[index].selected?
                                    "Select": "Selected",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                      color: !_bloc.similarProducts
                                      [index].selected?
                                      Colors.white:
                                      Hexcolor("#DADE66"),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                ),
```

Comment: check this [How to deselect the already selected item after tap on another item ListView in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115317/13701072)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only one item you can make a new value, lets call it selectedItem.
then on the FlatButton onPressed callback set the selectedItem to the value of the item you want to select ( the value can be the index, id or any unique identifier maybe the item it self ).

And then you can check the value in every item on the list if it's equal to display what you want.

This way when you select new item the old one would be replace so you end up with only 1 selected.